# Import Json file in Typescript : Error in terminal

Tags: json, typescript, visual-studio-code, tsconfig

I am new in typescript and I have 2 questions.

a. I want to import a simple JSON file in my typescript (main.ts) using the following code in visual studio code (3.6.2) editor:

```
import test from "./test.json";
console.log(test.name);
```

I also tried with `import * as test from "./test.json";`

While the JSON file (test.json) is the following:

```
{"name": "testing",
"age":25}
```

However, when I am typing "test.", typescript is giving the options for "name", "age" as the properties.

And the tsconfig.json file is following:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5", 
    "module": "commonjs",                     
    "strict": true, 
    "moduleResolution": "node",               
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true
  }
}
```

This code is throwing the following error:

```
Cannot find module './test.json'. Consider using '--resolveJsonModule' to import module with '.json' extension
```

Since the type definition is for old versions, I haven't used that. My typescript version is 3.6.3. The above mentioned 3 files are inside the same folder.

```
   -testfolder
     - main.ts
     - tsconfig.json
     - test.json
```

Though there are some other questions similar to this, but I couldn't find the problem in my code! I have also tested that with submile text 3 but it's also giving the same error!

b. If I want to parse a json data from a file where the file extension is different (not .json), how should I do that?

Thank you in advance for your time.

Comment: Is your json file at the same folder-level as main.ts? If it's not - import path should be relative to main.ts

Comment: Yes, all the files are in the same folder.

Comment: Then if you using VS Code - just restart it, should help.

Comment: Tried that, I restarted my pc too, but didn't help! :(

Answer (score 6):

Nihar,

I was able to reproduce the problem you mention.    I was also able to resolve the problem using the following **tsconfig.json**:

```
{
"compilerOptions": {
  /* Basic Options */
  "target": "es5",
  "module": "commonjs",
  "strict": true,
  "esModuleInterop": true,
  "resolveJsonModule": true
}, 
"files": ["main.ts"]
```

}

Of course, the added "files" section assumes your main file is named "main.ts".   Frankly I'm not sure why this works and your original does not, but when I use a **tsconfig.json** file, I try to put everything typescript needs to know in that one place.

Comment: I have just modified the tsconfig, restarted the editor, still it's not working!! Is there anything that I'm missing?!

Comment: Can you please tell me which editor and which version of typescript are you using?

Comment: I'm using VSCode (v1.37.1) and typescript 3.5.3 (also tested w/ typescript 3.6.3 ).   How about you?  What error do you get?   Are you only getting a message in the editor?

Comment: If you package everything it up as a repository and post a link, it would be easier to figure out what's going ont.

Comment: @Burt_Harris - This worked for me but it drives me crazy to not know "why" this works. I've tried a bunch of fixes & nothing solved but this. Any idea on how this works?

Answer (score 2):

try using a module. Review this documentation https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/namespaces-and-modules.html

// index.ts

```
import file from "./file.json";

console.log(file);
console.log(file.name);
```

// json.dt.ts

```
declare module "*.json" {
  const file: any;
  export default file;
}
```

Comment: I have already tried with type definition too. With the file extension "*.d.ts" and "*.dt.ts". It's giving the same error!

Comment: This test is done with (sublime text 3), the editor only took the changes when opening the project again

Comment: I have just tried with sublime text 3, but it is also giving the same error!

Comment: Try to configure a new TypeScript project (tsc --init). Add "resolveJsonModule" and the module for json files (do not modify anything else). Try translating the code (tsc). In case of generating JavaScript without errors, but follow the alert, check the text editor settings

Answer (score 0):

Given that you use VSCode and **all the files** are in the **same directory** and VSCode is opened from that directory **directly**, then your tsconfig works perfectly (for TS 3.6 at least).

Comment: Make sure that you have all the files (including tsconfig) in the same directory AND that VSCode is opened in that directory ONLY.

Comment: Yes. That is how I am trying but no luck :(

Comment: This leaves one option left...

How are you running TypeScript?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to launch your app with this command

```
npm run serve --resolveJsonModule
```

your mistake may disappear